# Multi-Group Unpivot in Oracle SQL returns incorrect number of rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the table below:

```
CREATE TABLE "XXSAMPLE2" 
(
"JG_INFO_V1" VARCHAR2(240 BYTE), 
"JG_INFO_V14" VARCHAR2(150 BYTE), 
"JG_INFO_V16" VARCHAR2(150 BYTE), 
"JG_INFO_V21" VARCHAR2(150 BYTE), 
"JG_INFO_V32" VARCHAR2(1996 BYTE), 
"JG_INFO_N3" NUMBER, 
"JG_INFO_N4" NUMBER, 
"JG_INFO_N11" NUMBER, 
"JG_INFO_N15" NUMBER, 
"JG_INFO_N30" NUMBER 
);
```

and the following records:

```
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_4','tns:P_14_1',3225.79,225.81,842,58.94,'VAT',859634,'EUR');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_3','tns:P_14_3',421.42,50.57,110,13.2,'KOREKTA',859635,'EUR');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_4','tns:',490.38,49.04,128,12.8,'KOREKTA',859635,'EUR');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_5','tns:P_14_4',122.6,6.13,32,1.6,'VAT',860621,'EUR');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_4','tns:P_14_1',3225.79,225.81,842,58.94,'VAT',860621,'EUR');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_4','tns:',-100,-10,-100,-10,'KOREKTA',859638,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_3','tns:P_14_3',-87,-10.44,-87,-10.44,'KOREKTA',859638,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_5','tns:P_14_5',40,4.4,40,4.4,'KOREKTA',859638,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_4','tns:P_14_1',-3225.79,-225.81,-842,-58.94,'VAT',860622,'EUR');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_5','tns:P_14_4',-122.6,-6.13,-32,-1.6,'VAT',860622,'EUR');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_5','tns:P_14_5',367.79,40.46,96,10.56,'KOREKTA',860622,'EUR');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_4','tns:',3225.79,322.58,842,84.2,'KOREKTA',860622,'EUR');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_4','tns:',30.06,3.01,30.06,3.01,'KOREKTA',863622,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_3','tns:P_14_3',74,8.88,74,8.88,'KOREKTA',863622,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_4','tns:',30.06,3.01,30.06,3.01,'KOREKTA',863625,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_5','tns:P_14_5',74,8.14,74,8.14,'KOREKTA',863625,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_4','tns:',115.16,11.53,30.06,3.01,'KOREKTA',863626,'EUR');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_3','tns:P_14_3',283.5,34.02,74,8.88,'KOREKTA',863626,'EUR');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_4','tns:P_14_1',-200,-14,-200,-14,'VAT',860619,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_4','tns:P_14_1',-123,-8.61,-123,-8.61,'VAT',860619,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_5','tns:P_14_4',-72,-3.6,-72,-3.6,'VAT',860619,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_4','tns:',48,4.8,48,4.8,'KOREKTA',860619,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_3','tns:P_14_3',200,24,200,24,'KOREKTA',860619,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_5','tns:P_14_5',369,40.59,369,40.59,'KOREKTA',860619,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('H','Krakowska',null,null,null,null,18,'AV',null,null);
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_5','tns:P_14_5',100,11,100,11,'KOREKTA',859619,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_5','tns:P_14_5',50,5.5,50,5.5,'KOREKTA',859624,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_3','tns:P_14_3',144,17.28,144,17.28,'KOREKTA',859624,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_4','tns:',-360.12,-36.01,-94,-9.4,'KOREKTA',859639,'EUR');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_5','tns:P_14_5',-122.6,-13.49,-32,-3.52,'KOREKTA',859639,'EUR');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_3','tns:P_14_3',114.93,13.79,30,3.6,'KOREKTA',859639,'EUR');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_4','tns:P_14_1',100,7,100,7,'VAT',859618,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_5','tns:P_14_4',72,3.6,72,3.6,'VAT',859621,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_4','tns:P_14_1',123,8.61,123,8.61,'VAT',859621,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_4','tns:P_14_1',200,14,200,14,'VAT',859621,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_5','tns:P_14_4',32,1.6,32,1.6,'VAT',859626,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_4','tns:P_14_1',842,58.94,842,58.94,'VAT',859626,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_3','tns:P_14_3',110,13.2,110,13.2,'KOREKTA',859627,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_4','tns:',128,12.8,128,12.8,'KOREKTA',859627,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_5','tns:P_14_4',32,1.6,32,1.6,'VAT',859628,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_4','tns:P_14_1',842,58.94,842,58.94,'VAT',859628,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_3','tns:P_14_3',110,13.2,110,13.2,'KOREKTA',859629,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_4','tns:',128,12.8,128,12.8,'KOREKTA',859629,'PLN');
Insert into XXSAMPLE2 (JG_INFO_V1,JG_INFO_V14,JG_INFO_V16,JG_INFO_N3,JG_INFO_N4,JG_INFO_N15,JG_INFO_N30,JG_INFO_V21,JG_INFO_N11,JG_INFO_V32) values ('AR','tns:P_13_5','tns:P_14_4',122.6,6.13,32,1.6,'VAT',859634,'EUR');
```

And I'm currently using the query below:

```
Select  invoice_id
    ,   Invoice_Type
    ,   BOX
    ,   functional_box
    ,   ROUND(sum(ENTERED_AMT), 2)  ENTERED_AMT_TOT
    ,   ROUND(sum(FUNC_AMT),2)      FUNC_AMT_TOT            
from    (
Select  jg_info_v14 box          -- taxable_box
    ,   Case When jg_info_v14 like 'tns:P_14%' and jg_info_v32 <> 'PLN' Then jg_info_v14||'W' else null end functional_box
    ,   jg_info_n3  func_amt     -- taxable_amt
    ,   jg_info_n15 entered_amt  -- entered_taxable_amount
    ,   jg_info_v21 Invoice_Type
    ,   jg_info_n11 invoice_id
    ,   jg_info_v32 invoice_currency_code
From    XXSAMPLE2
WHERE   jg_info_v1 IN ('AR', 'AP')
and     jg_info_v14 <> 'tns:'
union all
Select  jg_info_v16     box             -- tax_box
    ,   Case When jg_info_v16 like 'tns:P_14%' and jg_info_v32 <> 'PLN' Then jg_info_v16||'W' else null end functional_box
    ,   jg_info_n4      func_amt        -- tax_amt
    ,   jg_info_n30     entered_amt     -- entered_tax_amount
    ,   jg_info_v21     Invoice_Type
    ,   jg_info_n11     invoice_id
    ,   jg_info_v32     invoice_currency_code
From    XXSAMPLE2
WHERE   jg_info_v1 IN ('AR', 'AP')
and     jg_info_v16 <> 'tns:'
) tax_info
WHERE    invoice_id = 859639
group by 
     tax_info.invoice_id
,    tax_info.Invoice_Type
,    tax_info.BOX
,    tax_info.functional_box
;
```

and below are the results:

```
INVOICE_ID  INVOICE_TYPE    BOX         FUNCTIONAL_BOX  ENTERED_AMT_TOT FUNC_AMT_TOT
----------  ------------    ----------- --------------  --------------- -------------
859639      KOREKTA         tns:P_14_3  tns:P_14_3W                 3.6         13.79
859639      KOREKTA         tns:P_13_5                              -32        -122.6
859639      KOREKTA         tns:P_13_4                              -94       -360.12
859639      KOREKTA         tns:P_13_3                               30        114.93
859639      KOREKTA         tns:P_14_5  tns:P_14_5W               -3.52        -13.49
```

However, I would want to use `UNPIVOT` to have the below result:

```
INVOICE_ID  INVOICE_TYPE    BOX         AMOUNT      
----------  ------------    ----------- ------------
859639      KOREKTA         tns:P_14_3           3.6            
859639      KOREKTA         tns:P_13_5           -32
859639      KOREKTA         tns:P_13_4           -94
859639      KOREKTA         tns:P_13_3            30
859639      KOREKTA         tns:P_14_5         -3.52
859639      KOREKTA         tns:P_14_3W        13.79
859639      KOREKTA         tns:P_14_5W       -13.49
```

I tried the below query but i am getting incorrect values in the sum:

```
Select  distinct 
        jg_info_n11 invoice_id
    ,   jg_info_v21 invoice_type
    ,   jg_info_v32 currency_code
    ,   TRX_BOX
    ,   sum(func_amt) func_amt
    ,   sum(entered_amt) entered_amt
From    XXSAMPLE2
unpivot (TRX_BOX     FOR TRX_BOX_VALUES     IN (jg_info_v14, jg_info_v16))
unpivot (func_amt    FOR func_amt_values    IN (jg_info_n3, jg_info_n4))
unpivot (entered_amt FOR entered_amt_values IN (jg_info_n15, jg_info_n30))
WHERE   jg_info_v1 IN ('AR', 'AP')
and     TRX_BOX <> 'tns:'
AND     jg_info_n11 = 859639
group by jg_info_n11
    ,   jg_info_v21
    ,   jg_info_v32
    ,   TRX_BOX;
```

below are the results:

```
INVOICE_ID  INVOICE_TYPE    CURRENCY_CODE   TRX_BOX     FUNC_AMT    ENTERED_AMT     
----------  ------------    --------------  ----------- ----------- ---------------
859639      KOREKTA         EUR             tns:P_13_4      -792.26         -206.8
859639      KOREKTA         EUR             tns:P_14_5      -272.18         -71.04
859639      KOREKTA         EUR             tns:P_13_3       257.44           67.2
859639      KOREKTA         EUR             tns:P_14_3       257.44           67.2
859639      KOREKTA         EUR             tns:P_13_5      -272.18         -71.04
```

If i remove the aggregates, 20 records are being fetched, 4 times the expected results:

```
INVOICE_ID  INVOICE_TYPE    CURRENCY_CODE   TRX_BOX     FUNC_AMT    ENTERED_AMT     
----------  ------------    --------------  ----------- ----------- ---------------
859639      KOREKTA         EUR             tns:P_13_4  -36.01      -9.4
859639      KOREKTA         EUR             tns:P_13_5  -122.6      -3.52
859639      KOREKTA         EUR             tns:P_14_5  -13.49      -32
859639      KOREKTA         EUR             tns:P_14_5  -13.49      -3.52
859639      KOREKTA         EUR             tns:P_13_3  114.93      3.6
859639      KOREKTA         EUR             tns:P_14_5  -122.6      -3.52
859639      KOREKTA         EUR             tns:P_13_4  -36.01      -94
859639      KOREKTA         EUR             tns:P_13_3  114.93      30
859639      KOREKTA         EUR             tns:P_13_5  -122.6      -32
859639      KOREKTA         EUR             tns:P_14_3  114.93      30
859639      KOREKTA         EUR             tns:P_13_4  -360.12     -94
859639      KOREKTA         EUR             tns:P_13_3  13.79       3.6
859639      KOREKTA         EUR             tns:P_13_4  -360.12     -9.4
859639      KOREKTA         EUR             tns:P_13_5  -13.49      -32
859639      KOREKTA         EUR             tns:P_13_5  -13.49      -3.52
859639      KOREKTA         EUR             tns:P_14_5  -122.6      -32
859639      KOREKTA         EUR             tns:P_13_3  13.79       30
859639      KOREKTA         EUR             tns:P_14_3  114.93      3.6
859639      KOREKTA         EUR             tns:P_14_3  13.79       30
859639      KOREKTA         EUR             tns:P_14_3  13.79       3.6
```

It seems it's doing a `Merge Join Cartesian` with itself:

```
Plan hash value: 2179312268
 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT         |          |    24 | 28632 |    17   (6)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH UNIQUE             |          |    24 | 28632 |    17   (6)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   VIEW                   |          |    24 | 28632 |    16   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    UNPIVOT               |          |       |       |            |          |
|*  4 |     VIEW                 |          |    12 |   110K|     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      UNPIVOT             |          |       |       |            |          |
|*  6 |       VIEW               |          |     6 | 56364 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |        UNPIVOT           |          |       |       |            |          |
|*  8 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL| XXSAMPLE2 |     3 | 28374 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - filter("unpivot_view_025"."ENTERED_AMT" IS NOT NULL)
   4 - filter("unpivot_view_013"."FUNC_AMT" IS NOT NULL)
   6 - filter("unpivot_view_007"."TRX_BOX" IS NOT NULL AND 
              "unpivot_view_007"."TRX_BOX"<>'tns:')
   8 - filter(("XXSAMPLE2"."JG_INFO_V1"='AP' OR "XXSAMPLE2"."JG_INFO_V1"='AR') 
              AND "XXSAMPLE2"."JG_INFO_N11"=859639)
 
Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

Do I need to Add more conditions to the `UNPIVOT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you're unpivoting three times, and aggregating at the wrong level - aggregation shouldn't really be necessary at all, at least with the sample data.

You also need to exclude some of the values your current query returns - the functional amounts when functional box is null.

I think this non-union query gets only the data you want:

```sql
select  jg_info_n11 invoice_id
    ,   jg_info_v21 invoice_type
    ,   jg_info_v32 currency_code
    ,   case when jg_info_v14 = 'tns:' then null
             else jg_info_v14
        end as v14_box
    ,   case when jg_info_v14 = 'tns:' then null
             else jg_info_n15
        end as v14_amount
    ,   case when jg_info_v14 like 'tns:P_14%' and jg_info_v32 <> 'PLN' then jg_info_v14||'W'
        end as v14_func_box
    ,   case when jg_info_v14 like 'tns:P_14%' and jg_info_v32 <> 'PLN' then jg_info_n3
        end as v14_func_amount
    ,   case when jg_info_v16 = 'tns:' then null
             else jg_info_v16
        end as v16_box
    ,   case when jg_info_v16 = 'tns:' then null
             else jg_info_n30
        end as v16_amount
    ,   case when jg_info_v16 like 'tns:P_14%' and jg_info_v32 <> 'PLN' then jg_info_v16||'W'
        end as v16_func_box
    ,   case when jg_info_v16 like 'tns:P_14%' and jg_info_v32 <> 'PLN' then jg_info_n4
        end as v16_func_amount
from    XXSAMPLE2
where   jg_info_v1 IN ('AR', 'AP')
and     jg_info_n11 = 859639;
```

which gets:

```
INVOICE_ID INVOICE_TYPE CURRENCY_CODE V14_BOX    V14_AMOUNT V14_FUNC_BOX V14_FUNC_AMOUNT V16_BOX    V16_AMOUNT V16_FUNC_BOX V16_FUNC_AMOUNT
---------- ------------ ------------- ---------- ---------- ------------ --------------- ---------- ---------- ------------ ---------------
    859639 KOREKTA      EUR           tns:P_13_4        -94                                                                                
    859639 KOREKTA      EUR           tns:P_13_5        -32                              tns:P_14_5      -3.52 tns:P_14_5W           -13.49
    859639 KOREKTA      EUR           tns:P_13_3         30                              tns:P_14_3        3.6 tns:P_14_3W            13.79
```

And you can then unpivot that, with a single command:

```
select invoice_id, invoice_type, box, amount
from (
  select  jg_info_n11 invoice_id
      ,   jg_info_v21 invoice_type
      ,   jg_info_v32 currency_code
      ,   case when jg_info_v14 = 'tns:' then null
               else jg_info_v14
          end as v14_box
      ,   case when jg_info_v14 = 'tns:' then null
               else jg_info_n15
          end as v14_amount
      ,   case when jg_info_v14 like 'tns:P_14%' and jg_info_v32 <> 'PLN' then jg_info_v14||'W'
          end as v14_func_box
      ,   case when jg_info_v14 like 'tns:P_14%' and jg_info_v32 <> 'PLN' then jg_info_n3
          end as v14_func_amount
      ,   case when jg_info_v16 = 'tns:' then null
             else jg_info_v16
          end as v16_box
      ,   case when jg_info_v16 = 'tns:' then null
               else jg_info_n30
          end as v16_amount
      ,   case when jg_info_v16 like 'tns:P_14%' and jg_info_v32 <> 'PLN' then jg_info_v16||'W'
          end as v16_func_box
      ,   case when jg_info_v16 like 'tns:P_14%' and jg_info_v32 <> 'PLN' then jg_info_n4
          end as v16_func_amount
  from    XXSAMPLE2
  where   jg_info_v1 IN ('AR', 'AP')
  and     jg_info_n11 = 859639
)
unpivot (
  (box, amount)
  for x in (
    (v14_box, v14_amount) as 1,
    (v14_func_box, v14_func_amount) as 2,
    (v16_box, v16_amount) as 3,
    (v16_func_box, v16_func_amount) as 4
  )
);
```

which gets:

```
INVOICE_ID INVOICE_TYPE BOX              AMOUNT
---------- ------------ ------------ ----------
    859639 KOREKTA      tns:P_13_4          -94
    859639 KOREKTA      tns:P_13_5          -32
    859639 KOREKTA      tns:P_14_5        -3.52
    859639 KOREKTA      tns:P_14_5W      -13.49
    859639 KOREKTA      tns:P_13_3           30
    859639 KOREKTA      tns:P_14_3          3.6
    859639 KOREKTA      tns:P_14_3W       13.79
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1b0ef6e823450ab8f33b6d40d6e15cc6)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get an Answer from the amazing people over at [AskTom Forum](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9543438900346903322) and below are the details:

> When you have multiple sets of columns you want to unpivot, chaining
> unpivot operations multiplies rows in your results.
>
> The trick is to provide a comma-separated list of the columns you want
> to appear in your results before FOR. And each group of source columns
> that will provide these values. For example:

```
  unpivot include nulls (
    ( trx_box, entered_amt_values, func_amt ) for cols in ( 
      ( jg_info_v14, jg_info_n15, jg_info_n3 ) as 'trx_box',
      ( jg_info_v16, jg_info_n30, jg_info_n4 ) as 'func_amt'
    )
  )
```

> Which gives:

```
with rws as (
 select jg_info_v14 
  , jg_info_n3 
  , jg_info_n11 
  , jg_info_n4 
  , jg_info_n15
  , jg_info_v16   
  , jg_info_v21  
  , jg_info_n30 
  , jg_info_v32
 from   xxsample2
 where  jg_info_v1 IN ('AR', 'AP')
)
  select jg_info_n11,
         jg_info_v21,
         jg_info_v32,
         case
           when trx_box like 'tns:P_14%' and jg_info_v32 <> 'PLN' 
           then trx_box || 'W'
           else null
         end functional_box,
         entered_amt_values,
         func_amt
  from   rws
  unpivot include nulls (
    ( trx_box, entered_amt_values, func_amt ) for cols in ( 
      ( jg_info_v14, jg_info_n15, jg_info_n3 ) as 'trx_box',
      ( jg_info_v16, jg_info_n30, jg_info_n4 ) as 'func_amt'
    )
  )
  where  jg_info_n11 = 859639
  and    trx_box <> 'tns:';
```

And below are the results:

```
JG_INFO_N11    JG_INFO_V21    JG_INFO_V32    FUNCTIONAL_BOX    ENTERED_AMT_VALUES     FUNC_AMT   
        859639 KOREKTA        EUR            <null>                              -94     -360.12 
        859639 KOREKTA        EUR            <null>                              -32      -122.6 
        859639 KOREKTA        EUR            tns:P_14_5W                       -3.52      -13.49 
        859639 KOREKTA        EUR            <null>                               30      114.93 
        859639 KOREKTA        EUR            tns:P_14_3W                         3.6       13.79
```

It's pretty close to what I want to accomplish, which really helped me understand how multi-group Unpivots work.